# Return a string from chrome.history.search() callback

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to return the last URL from the callback in chrome.history.search http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history.html#method-search

So far my method looks like this:

```
var getLastUrl = function() {
    chrome.history.search({
        text: '',
        maxResults: 1
    }, function(results) {
        console.log(results);
        console.log(results[0].url);
        return 'Return value: ' + results[0].url;
    });
};
```

Here is the output from my background page console when running getLastUrl()
[image: output]

As you can see there is a return object and console.log(results[0].url) is working but the callback is returning an undefined value.. how can I get around this so that it returns the proper url?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Figured out how to do it myself, it's because of the asynchronous nature of the chrome extension api, this helped me [How to make a function wait until a callback has been called using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010288/how-to-make-a-function-wait-until-a-callback-has-been-called-using-node-js).

Basically I was getting undefined because the function completed without waiting for the callback (since it's asynchronous).

So instead of doing

```
var getLastUrl = function() {
chrome.history.search({
    text: '',
    maxResults: 1
}, function(results) {
    console.log(results);
    console.log(results[0].url);
    return 'Return value: ' + results[0].url;
});
};

var lastUrl = getLastUrl();
```

I edited the function to look like:

```
var getLastUrl = function(callback) {
chrome.history.search({
    text: '',
    maxResults: 1
}, function(results) {
    console.log(results);
    console.log(results[0].url);
    callback(results[0].url);
});
};
```

Then you can access the url using:

```
getLastUrl(function(lastUrl) {
  // now you can use lastUrl here
});
```

Hope this helps anyone who runs across this!