# Redirect to new URL using onBeforeRequest and chrome.tabs.query (Chrome Extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Good time.

I have some interesting idea for which have to do changing URL after inputing pushing "enter" by user.

My manifest file:

```
 {
  "name": "The Pirate Bay_2",
  "description": "Redirect The Pirate Bay to a different host",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Saving Studio generator",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"

    },
    "background": {"scripts":["redirect.js"]},
    "content_scripts": [
   {
     "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
     "js": ["background.js"]
   }
   ],
  "permissions": 
  [ 
    "webRequest", 
    "https://www.amazon.com/", 
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab"
    ]

}
```

My redirect.js file:

```
var host = "https://2ch.hk/b/";

chrome.tabs.query({
    'active': true, 'currentWindow': true
    }, function (tabs) {
    var url = tabs[0].url;
    host = host+url;
    console.log(url);
    });

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(  
    function(details) {

        if (localStorage.check_box == "true"){
            console.log("start_1");

         return {redirectUrl: host};
        }
    },
    {
        urls: ["https://www.amazon.com/" ],
        types: ["main_frame", "sub_frame", "stylesheet", "script", "image", "object", "xmlhttprequest", "other"]
    },

    ["blocking"]
);
```

Main is to how to **take entered URL**, change it by some regex pattern, **return resulting URL** to redirect to it. How it's possible to do? How to insert *chrome.tabs.query* inside *onBeforeRequest* or this needn't and there is another way?

Big thanks

Comment: See [Synchronous call in Google Chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22054013) and [How to wait for an asynchronous method's callback return value?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15130214)

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do something similar using the chrome storage API which is also asynchronous. What I did was put the web request listener inside the callback of the async function. So in your case:

```
var host = "https://2ch.hk/b/";
chrome.tabs.query(
    {
        'active': true, 'currentWindow': true
    }, 
    function (tabs) {
        var url = tabs[0].url;
        host = host+url;
        console.log(url);
    }
    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(  
        function(details) {
            if (localStorage.check_box == "true"){
                console.log("start_1");
                return {redirectUrl: host};
            }
        },
        {
            urls: ["https://www.amazon.com/" ],
            types: ["main_frame", "sub_frame", "stylesheet", "script", "image", "object", "xmlhttprequest", "other"]
        },
        ["blocking"]
    );
);
```

I haven't tested this but it's what I did when I needed to use the storage API, so give it a try.