# JSON parse error: Cannot read property

Tags: javascript, json

I have created some little jt code, but it gives me error

```
function Mind(){
    var request = "request";
    var reply = "reply";
    var words = '';

    this.Reply = function(){
        if(request == words.nouns[0].noun){
            reply = words.nouns[0].noun;
        }
        else
            reply = this.words.nouns[0].noun;
    }

    this.SetRequest = function(req){
        request = req;
    }

    this.GetReply = function(){
        return reply;
    }

    this.Parse = function(u){
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = u;
        var result;
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                words = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        return result;
    }

    this.Construct = function(){
        words = this.Parse('mind/words.json');
    }}

    var mind = new Mind();
    mind.Parse('mind/words.json');
```

and here is my json file

```
{
    "nouns": [
        {"noun": "child"},
        {"noun": "father"}
    ]
}
```

In command live all goes well, but when I run this code, appears error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nouns' of undefined

Comment: Also see Stackoverflow FAQ : [Access / process objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mutliple errors. The most fundamental one is that your code ignores that XMLHttpRequest is async, and wont return a value in the same way as "regular" functions. Read about it here: [How to make a function wait until a callback has been called using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010288/how-to-make-a-function-wait-until-a-callback-has-been-called-using-node-js/5010339#5010339). The TL;DR is that you **have to** pass in a "callback-function" to your parse-method and "return" your value using that function, instead of using a return-statement. Google for "javascript callbacks" and read a few tutorials if this concept is new to you!

You also have some minor errors, like returning `result` from `Parse`, but never actually setting `result` to anything. Also `words` is being assigned in multiple places in a way that doesn't really make sense. But both of these things will go away when you solve the sync/async issues.

**EDIT:**

Essentially the fix looks like this:

```
this.Parse = function(u, callback){ // this "callback" is new
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = u;
    var result;
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            words = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            callback(null, words); // we're "returning" the words here
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    // no return statement here!
}

this.Construct = function(){
    this.Parse('mind/words.json', function(error, words) {
        // here you can use your words!
    });
}}
```

Comment: Hi @Jakob . Please can you tell me more , how can I fix it ? Thank you

Comment: there is an error Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function

Comment: Thank you, all goes well