# NodeJS wait asynchronous

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I've been reading about NodeJS and callbacks but I've been unable to get the grasp of it.
[Wait for function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010288/how-to-make-a-function-wait-until-a-callback-has-been-called-using-node-js) Here they explain why this happens but I don't understand how to do it with 2 nested functions.

I have a function that calls another function that will select a row from PostgreSQL Simple as that.
Problem is, my function that looks up this row always returns before the select finishes so it doesn't work.

```
function testing() {
  var p=getTrackerId("123");
  console.log(p);
}



function getTrackerId(id) {
  var tracker_id="TEST";
  pg.connect(conString, function(err, client, done) {
    if(err) {
      return console.error('error fetching client from pool', err);
    }   
    tracker_id="THIS1";
    var q = squel.select()
      .from("access")
      .where("unique_id = ?",id)
      .toString();

    client.query(q, function(err, result) {
      if(result.rows[0]!=undefined){
        tracker_id=result.rows[0].tracker_id;
      }

      done();
      tracker_id="THIS3";
      if(err) {
        return console.error('error running query', err);
      }
    });


  });
  return tracker_id;
}
```

This function will always return "TEST" and, therefore, p will always be TEST.
Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-04/async-method-patterns

Comment: You need to get familiar with promises.