# Callback not called Node.Js for a router application

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

My current code is

```
resizer.resize(filepath, parsedUrl, fullDestinationPath, function() {
        return self.send(response, 200, {'Content-Type': mime.lookup(fullDestinationPath)}, fs.createReadStream(fullDestinationPath));
    });
```

The resize runs to

```
Resizer.prototype.resize = function (filepath, parsedUrl, fullDestinationPath) {
         this.read(filepath, parsedUrl, fullDestinationPath);
};
```

Which then calls

```
Resizer.prototype.read = function(filepath, parsedUrl, fullDestinationPath){ 
    something.then(function (somethingElse) {
      // Not relevant for question
   }).catch(function (err) {
       console.error(err);
   });
};
```

I've had a `console.log(1);` after `this.read` in the second code snippet to guarantee that it was completely running through it. But returning to my first snippet it doesn't call my callback. The reason I'm using a callback there is because if I don't the send will be executed before a file is completely saved unless it's a very small file, so `self.send` needs to be called AFTER `.resize` which is why I am attempting to use a callback.

I've tried multiple things thinking a syntax error might have be the issue or that it was hanging on something, but I've verified it isn't and it is simply not calling the callback. Did I make some kind of obvious mistake? How do I make it call the callback?

I have read questions/answers like this one [How to make a function wait until a callback has been called using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010288/how-to-make-a-function-wait-until-a-callback-has-been-called-using-node-js) and understand how it works and implemented it in the same manner, but it's not working for me and I do not see why. Thanks for taking the time to read through this.

EDIT: After fixing the issue with Roberts answer I've removed the callback and changed the code to this, I am using promises instead of callbacks tho:
Snippet 1:

```
resizer
        .resize(filepath, parsedUrl, fullDestinationPath)
        .then(function() {
            return self.send(response, 200, {'Content-Type': mime.lookup(fullDestinationPath)}, fs.createReadStream(fullDestinationPath));
        });
```

Snippet 2:

```
Resizer.prototype.resize = function (filepath, parsedUrl, fullDestinationPath) {
   return this.read(filepath, parsedUrl, fullDestinationPath);
};
```

Snippet 3:

```
Resizer.prototype.read = function(filepath, parsedUrl, fullDestinationPath){
    return Jimp.read(filepath)
        .then(function() {
            return //tons of irrelevant code
         })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.error(err);
        });
};
```

Comment: I don't see any callback being passed to or used by your resize function.

Comment: The return self.send part is the part that isn't being called. Don't you call that a callback? Also using console.log I have verified that it is running through all code and not hanging anywhere, it is just not getting to the return. The self is just a var self = this; in a upper part of the code since the meaning of this changes when I put another function around it.

Comment: `self.send()` is a command inside an anonymous function definition which you pass as an argument to `resize`, but as mentioned here, `resize` does not accept a callback in its parameters list (it only accepts filepath, parsedUrl and fullDestinationPath)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Resizer.prototype.resize` doesn't take a callback argument to begin with, so even though you pass one from your main code, there's nothing done with it.

The same goes for `this.read()`: it has no callback argument either.

Try this:

```
Resizer.prototype.resize = function (filepath, parsedUrl, fullDestinationPath, callback) {
  this.read(filepath, parsedUrl, fullDestinationPath, callback);
};
```

And:

```
Resizer.prototype.read = function(filepath, parsedUrl, fullDestinationPath, callback){ 
  something.then(function (somethingElse) {
    callback(null, somethingElse); 
  }).catch(function (err) {
    console.error(err);
    callback(err);
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you it is working now, I didn't realize I had to pass the callback as a parameter, I've had to edit your second snippet a tiny bit to make it work, I'll edit the code I used in my main post.

Comment: There's nothing really special about callbacks, they are just functions that get passed around and called once an operation has completed :D

Comment: Thanks I won't forget how to properly use callbacks for sure now.

Comment: I added the code I ended up with in a edit, is that a proper way to solve it?

Comment: @StrahBehry yeah that looks okay, although you're now using promises instead of callbacks. Which is totally fine and, in fact, will allow you to drop the `callback` arguments completely (promises are a different way of handling asynchronous code, an alternative to callbacks).