# Firebase return output from function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new in firebase and I'm trying to pass a `$variable` in a function to check if the `$variable` is exists.

```
function ifExistWaybillNo(waybill_no)
{
  var databaseRef = firebase.database().ref('masterlist');
  databaseRef.orderByChild("waybill_no").equalTo(waybill_no).on('value', function(snapshot){
    alert(snapshot.exists()); //Alert true or false
  });
}
```

The above function work's fine but when I changed `alert(snapshot.exists());` to `return snapshot.exists();` it doesn't working. It just return undefined, which should return `true` or `false.`

How can I do this? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost everything Firebase does is asynchronous. When you call the function `ifExistWaybillNo` it expects an immediate return, not to wait. So before your `databaseRef.orderByChild("waybill_no")` is finished the statement that called the function has already decided the return is `undefined`.

The way to fix this is by passing a callback function and using the return there. An exact explanation of this is done very well here: [return async call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010288/how-to-make-a-function-wait-until-a-callback-has-been-called-using-node-js).

You just need to rename some of the functions and follow syntax used there.

To start:

```
function(waybill_no, callback) { 
    databaseRef.orderByChild("waybill_no").equalTo(waybill_no).on('value', function(snapshot) {
    var truth = snapshot.exists();
    callback(truth); // this will "return" your value to the original caller
  });
}
```

**Remember**, almost everything Firebase is asynchronous.

Comment: No problem, happy coding.