# node.js - nesting request, wait until request function is done

Tags: javascript, node.js

I use the following code

```
request(firstparams, function () {
    var secondparams = {
    // ******
    };

    request(secondparams, function () {
        for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
            var thirdparams = {
            // ******
            };

            request(thirdparams, function () {
                console.log('foo');
            });
        }
        console.log('bar');
    });
});
```

and want to get the result like:

```
foo
foo
foo
bar
```

but the result is:

```
bar
foo
foo
foo
```

Sorry for my poor English, if there is something ambiguity，I would try my best to explain. Thanks a lot ^ ^

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010288/how-to-make-a-function-wait-until-a-callback-has-been-called-using-node-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easies way to do what you want would be to use ['async' module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) which is the classical module to handle async problems.

To run 3rd calls in parallel and log 'bar' after each of them is finished you would do something like this:

```js
const async = require('async');

let asyncFunctions = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i+= 1) {
 let thirdParams = {...};

 asyncFunctions.push(function (callback) {
  request(thirdparams, function (err, data) {
   console.log('foo');
   callback(err, data);
  });
 });
}

async.parallel(asyncFunctions, function (err, data) {
 console.log('bar');
});
```

You are using callbacks. But there are also other ways to handle asynchrony in node.js like: promises, generators and async/await functions from ES7.

I think that may be useful for you do check out some articles like [this one](http://stackabuse.com/avoiding-callback-hell-in-node-js/).