# How to get data from function to variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm learning node.js and I have a problem. How to get data from function to variable?

```
function loadOrInitializeTaskArray(file, cb) {
        fs.exists(file, function(exists) {
                var tasks = [];
                if (exists) {
                    fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
                            if (err) throw err;
                            var data = data.toString();
                            var tasks = JSON.parse(data || '[]');
                            cb(tasks);
                    })
                } else {
                        cb([]);
                }
        })
}



function listTasks(file) {
        loadOrInitializeTaskArray(file, function(tasks) {
                for (var i in tasks) {
                        console.log(tasks[i]);
                }
        })
}
```

Function listTasks works correctly, but I would like create own function, for example customListTasks:

```
function customListTasks(file) {
        var list = loadOrInitializeTaskArray(file, function(){});
        console.log(list);
}
```

This not return me errors, but console.log on list return me "undefined". How can I get this data to variable list?

Comment: use Bluebird coroutine function and using that you can yield promises

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010288/how-to-make-a-function-wait-until-a-callback-has-been-called-using-node-js

Comment: You cannot expect to get an asynchronous result synchronously. You'll have to get it asynchronously (callback, promise).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: you can not.

Because the loading in `loadOrInitializeTaskArray` is asynchronous, all the magic has to happen in the callback that you are passing. You cannot just 'return' a value from it.

**Option 1:** Place all logic that depends on the loaded data in the anonymous function that you pass as callback.

```
var list = loadOrInitializeTaskArray(file, function(tasks){
    console.log(tasks);
});
```

**Option 2:** Use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). They work essentially like callbacks, but are slightly more flexible and make chaining easier.