# Node.js - How to make a function wait to finish before continuing

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function that looks like this:

```
const XML = '.xml code';

var array = [];
var i = 0; //counter

XMLExtract(XML, 'loc', false, (error, element) => {
    if (error) {
        throw new Error(error);
    }

    array[i] = element; 

    console.log(array[i]);

    function_name(array[i]); //imported function from external .js

    i++;

});
```

Basically I want to run *function()* to return the response that it gives and then run *function()* again with the new parameter. However, the above code doesn't work, it just overlaps.

I've also checked previous solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5010339 but I think I don't really know how to implement it. Any suggestion?

**UPDATE:** `external.js`

```
module.exports = function() {

this.function_name = function() {

(async function() {

 ...

await instance.exit();

}());
};
};
```

Comment: The link you included has the answer right there. Edit the function in `external.js` and include a callback parameter, then run that callback at the end of the function.

Comment: 1) I wouldn't name a function `function`. 2) You're only calling the function once. If I understand correctly, you're looking to do `someFunction(element, someOtherFunction);`? 3) You can get rid of `i` and just do `array.push`.

Comment: @BrettBeatty 1) It was just for reference purpose. 2) `XMLExtract(XML, 'loc', false, (error, element)` is actually a loop and I'm looking to first run `function()`, wait until it finishes, then increase the counter by 1 and then run the same function with the new parameter. 3) I will do it, thanks :)

Comment: @VictorC. I mean I don't really understand it as I'm a newbie in Javascript/Node.js. If you could help me adjusting it using the code above, it would help a lot.

Comment: "*`// This is a loop`*" - no, it's a comment. Please post your actual code. If you meant recursion (which is the correct approach indeed), where do you define `function_name`?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, I know it sounds weird, but forgive me as I'm a newbie in Javascript/Node.js. I was referring to `XMLExtract()` because basically when you pass in the parameter XML (which is in this case is a .xml code), it outputs the urls. I've updated the code.

Comment: I'm having a hard time reading all of your functions, but if you return the result of the call to the async function in `external.js` from `this.function_name`, you could then in your main code do `function_name(element).then(function_name)` and have it called again with its result.

Comment: Take a look into promises. It may help you. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Callbacks & promises are the core of asynchronous development. You really need to understand those.

Comment: I'm actually stuck trying to recreate what I think is your issue in this simple example it looks like you are getting the behavior you are looking for https://repl.it/JIGV/5 am I missing something?