# Example of synchronous Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want an example of synchronous javascript.

Let's say I have three functions

```
fun1();
fun2();
fun3();
```

They all log some data. But I want the second function fun2() to pause the script for 5 seconds and then continue.

Doing setTimeout has not worked as it is async.

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010288/how-to-make-a-function-wait-until-a-callback-has-been-called-using-node-js

Comment: That's async. I want Synchronous.

Comment: yes. Just for a demo.

Comment: @krv why do you want to have that synchronous. Even if it would be possible you would completely block the browser window for 5 seconds, which is on the one hand bad for user experience, because the user cannot do anything anymore, and worst of all it also might trigger a long running script warning in the browser, asking the user if the script should be stoped.

Comment: Believe me, you don't *want* to pause everything for 5 seconds.

Comment: Just use this two lines of code in ur fun2() and it will work as expected. var dd = new Date().getTime() + 5000;
while (new Date().getTime() < dd) {}

Comment: Yes, I Understand async is better but just out of curiosity wanted to know how can this be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a single threaded language, so by default, all tasks are synchronous. So `func3` will be called after `func2`.

But if you have any async task inside `func2` like `setTimeout` or `XHR`, then the sequence will break.

In such cases, you have 2 options, i.e. `Callback` and `Promises`.

```js
function func1(){
  var num = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i< 1000; i++){
    num += i;
  }
  console.log('func1: ', num);
}

function func2(){
  var num = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i< 1000000; i++){
    num += i;
  }
  console.log('func2: ', num);
}

function func3(){
  var num = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i< 10000; i++){
    num += i;
  }
  console.log('func3: ', num);
}

func1();
func2();
func3();
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript goes out of it's way to avoid blocking the event loop. As such writing a function that purposely blocks the loop for a given time is very unnatural.

Having said that, and only if you promise never to use it for anything other than a demonstrations, you can do something like this:

```
function fun1(){
  console.log("done in fun1")
  return
}

function fun3(){
  console.log("done in fun3")
  return
}

function fun2(){
  var then = new Date().getTime() + 5000; 

  // wait five seconds the hard way

  while(new Date().getTime() < then) {
  };
  console.log("done in fun2")
  return
}

fun1()
fun2()
fun3()
```

Comment: It should additional be mentioned that `while(new Date().getTime() < then){}` will result in a cpu usage of 100% for one core for 5 seconds.