# Node.js wait for all files read in the loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to the javascript/node.js event driven paradigm.

I need to stop the for after forEach to make sure all files have been read and then I continue. How should I implement `wait_for_all_files_read()` in this context?

```
my_list.forEach(function(element) {
  fs.readFile(element.file_path, function(err, data)  {
    if(err) throw err;
    element.obj=JSON.parse(data);
  });
});
wait_for_all_files_read(); <-----------
analyze(my_list)
```

Neither solution [[1]](https://medium.com/@nodejs_recipes/how-to-make-a-function-wait-until-a-callback-has-been-called-using-node-js-c29b36a8e02) or [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010288/how-to-make-a-function-wait-until-a-callback-has-been-called-using-node-js) work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I would do that:

1. Promisify fs.readFile (by using, for example Bluebird)
2. Mark the function as async
3. Make a list of callbacks (my_list.map instead of forEach)
4. "await Promise.all(myListOfCallbacks)"
5. Next line after await will be executed after all the operations been finished

Something like that:

```js
const {promisisfy} = require('util')
const fs = require('fs')
const readFile = promisify(fs.readFile)

const fileNames = getFilenamesArray();

async function executeMe() {
  try {
    const arrayWithFilesContent = await Promise.all(
      fileNames.map(name => readFile(name))
    );
    return analyze(arrayWithFilesContent);
  }
  catch (err) {
    handleError(err)
  }
}

executeMe();
```

Comment: but `readFIle` has a callback inside itself. How to consider that?

Comment: when it's promisified it returns promise. We can use promise .then (or await) instead of providing a callback as an argument.

Comment: So, where should I place `if(err) throw err;` and `element.obj=JSON.parse(data);`?

Comment: you can remove try/catch block, than the error will be thrown by the Promise.all. regarding the elements - you can do it in the loop AFTER the Promise.all

Comment: I became very confused.

Comment: What is not clear for you? I can explain if you want.

Comment: in your code, `readFile(name)` has no callback. How does it use the result of reading the file?

Comment: arrayWithFilesContent will have an array of all the results. You'll get the results in quasi-synchronous way.

Comment: const content = await readFile(fileName); // promisified, not the original fs. readFile!

Comment: The output, `arrayWithFilesContent`, is `[ <Buffer 7b 0a 20 20 20 ....` which is not human readable. I am doing wrong?

Comment: You need to specify the encoding. you can try to change the call 
from readFile(name) to readFile(name, 'utf8') for example (if you have unicode UTF-8 file, of course).

Comment: Then, I need to know which output belong to which input so I have to use an iteration and use the index. wouldn't be easier using `var contents = fs.readFileSync('DATA', 'utf8');`

Comment: It's possible to do it in sync way as well, and if you have something like command line utility I would recommend to do that, but for typical request/response is better to avoid blocking API.

Answer (score 4):

I can suggest you to rewrite the code to promise - it will make much easy to deal with it

```
const {promisisfy} = require('util')
const fs = require('fs')
const readFile = promisify(fs.readFile)

const fileNames = getFilenamesSomehow() // <-- returns array with path, e.g. ["./package.json", "/etc/hosts", "/etc/passwd"]

Promise.all(fileNames.map(name => readFile(name)))
.then(arrayWithFilesContent => analyze(arrayWithFilesContent))
.catch(err => handleError(err))
```

Next step what you may do - move the code to async/await functions

**UPD**

Assume you need read only one file, then parse it data to json and analyze the result somehow.

It this case you can do next:

```
readFile(singleFileName)
.then(function (singleFileContent) {
   return JSON.parse(singleFileContent)
})
.then(function (singleFileContentInJson) {
   return analyze(singleFileContentInJson)
})
.catch(funciton (error) {
  //here you can process all errors from functions above: reading file error, JSON.parse error, analyze error...
  console.log(error)
})
```

Then assume you need to analyze bunch of files

```
const fileNames = [...] // array with file names
// this create an array of promises, each of them read one file and returns the file content in JSON
const promises = fileNames.map(function (singleFileName) {
    return readFile(singleFileName)
    .then(function (singleFileContent) {
       return JSON.parse(singleFileContent)
    })
})

// promise all resolves (calls callback in 'then') all of promises in array are resolved and pass to then callback array with result of each promise
Promise.all(promises)
  .then(function (arrayWithResults) {
    return analyze(arrayWithResults)
  })
  // catch callback calls if one of promises in array rejects with error from the promise - so you can handle e.g. read file error or json parsing error here
  .catch(function (error) {
    //here you can handle any error
    console.log(error)
  })
```

Try to google some article to read how does promises work.
E. g. you can start form [mdn article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: can I use `function(name) {...}` instead of `name => readFile(name)`?

Comment: inside `readFile`  I have another callback, does it wait for all the inner callbacks as well?

Comment: nope. `Promisify` function just wrap function that has been passed as parameter with promise.

Comment: but `readFIle` has a callback inside itself. How to consider that?

Comment: Also, where should I place `if(err) throw err;` and `element.obj=JSON.parse(data);`?