# Is it possible to asynchronously wait for a Node.js Event Emitter 'event.on()' to populate, before executing the rest of the function?

Tags: node.js, events, eventemitter

Sample code:

```
import { EventEmitter } from 'node:events'
let bus = new EventEmitter()

async function demo(){

    
    let foo


    const listen = async function (channelName, callback){ 

        await bus.on(channelName, data => { callback(data) })

    }


    await listen('test', data => { 

        foo = data 

    })


    // Artificially introducing a delay fixes this
    // while (foo == undefined){ await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000)) }

    // but without the day returns 'undefined'
    console.log(foo)

}
demo()
```

I suspect this is just an issue of me not being familiar with the correct async syntax / structure.

I have tried a dozen variations of adding 'await', but no luck.

Info appreciated!

---

thanks to [trincot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5459839/trincot) at the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78113747/19651059), and the same method at this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65368748/19651059), it's up and working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create a promise that resolves when the `on` event occurs. This you can do with `new Promise` and calling `resolve` when that event occurs.

Something like:

```
const channelData = (bus, channelName) => 
    new Promise(resolve => bus.on(channelName, resolve));

async function demo() {
    const foo = await channelData(bus, 'test');
    console.log(foo);
}

demo();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works.  I found that this still works without 'bus' as a param, also, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Yes, it also works without `bus` as argument, but it is better practice for a function to not have to rely on a global variable. Of course, if in reality you have this in a class, and `bus` is an instance property, then it is fine to do it without that argument, and have the method use `this.bus`.

Comment: Thank you.  Is the following bad practice? :  I have one single emitter for the whole app,  from which I created three utility functions ('emit', 'listen', and now this promise-based 'wait'), all three of which functions I export globally and use throughout the app.   It is very convenient, but it will cause problems?  Slava Heroiam

Comment: No it will not cause problems.

Comment: Appreciate you thanks again