# Javascript - Custom Confirm Dialog - replacing JS confirm

Tags: javascript

This may be a easy answer-

In my JS I've replaced JS's confirm function with my own.  Which basically and simply looks like this:

```
function confirm(i){
    var options = '<br/><br/><input class="button1" value="Yes" type="button" onclick="return true"> <input class="button1" value="No" type="button" onclick="return false">';
    $('#text').html(i+options);
    $('#confirmDiv').fadeIn('fast');
}
```

Obviously the return true / false didn't work, or else I wouldn't be asking!

In another function i've got (So you get the picture):

```
    var con = confirm("Are you sure you'd like to remove this course?");
    if(!con){return;}
```

How can I get confirm to return the value directly?  I'd assume it's return {this.value} or so?

Thanks!

Comment: What are the contents of confirmDiv?

Comment: Not easily possible. Normally a `confirm` waits until the user has provided an answer. Since Javascript doesn't have a wait/sleep you have to work around this issue by using a callback.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you wait for javascript callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436608/can-you-wait-for-javascript-callback)

Comment: another example how do it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457750/form-confirm-before-submit/12357337#12357337

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is that your custom confirm isn't *modal*. That means that when your confirm is shown, the code runs on. There is no chance for you to wait for the user's choice within `confirm()` and return it from there.

As far as I know, there is no way to emulate the behaviour of a modal confirmation dialog in Javascript (except for the non-standard [`ShowModalDialog()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.showModalDialog).)

The usual way of doing this is adding a `function() { ... }` callback to each button's `click` event, and doing whatever the "ok" click is supposed to do in there.

Answer (score 5):

My way around this problem was to add some arbitrary data to the object, and check for that data on click. If it existed, proceed with the function as normal, otherwise confirm with a yes/no (in my case using a jqtools overlay). If the user clicks yes - insert the data in the object, simulate another click and wipe the data. If they click no, just close the overlay.

Here is my example:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    if ($(this).data('confirmed')) {
        // Do stuff
    } else {
        confirm($(this));
    }
});
```

And this is what I did to override the confirm function (using a jquery tools overlay):

```
window.confirm = function(obj){
    $('#dialog').html('\
        <div>\
            <h2>Confirm</h2>\
            <p>Are you sure?</p>\
            <p>\
                <button name="confirm" value="yes" class="facebox-btn close">Yes</button>\
                <button name="confirm" value="no" class="facebox-btn close">No</button>\
            </p>\
        </div>').overlay().load();
    $('button[name=confirm]').click(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == 'yes') {
            $('#dialog').overlay().close();
            obj.data('confirmed', true).click().removeData('confirmed');
        } else {
            $('#dialog').overlay().close();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found another **hacked** solution to emulate the modale dialog like mentioned from Pekka 웃 before. If you break the JS execution there is no need to loop in a while(true). After retrieving the users input (click) we can go on with JS execution while calling the origin method again with eval and returning the users choice as boolean.
I created a small jsfiddle with jquery and notyjs to simply show my solution:
[jsfiddle: Overriding native modal confirm alert](https://jsfiddle.net/mitchobrian/07vmLfyw/29/)

Here again the important code:

```
/** confirm as noty.JS **/
var calleeMethod2 = null;
var returnValueOfConfirm = null;
var args = null;
var calleeMethod = null;
var refreshAfterClose = null;
var savedConfirm = window.confirm;
window.confirm = function(obj) {
    // check if the callee is a real method
    if (arguments.callee.caller) {
        args = arguments.callee.caller.arguments;
        calleeMethod = arguments.callee.caller.name;
    } else {
        // if confirm is called as if / else - rewrite orig js confirm box
        window.confirm = savedConfirm;
        return confirm(obj);
    }
    if (calleeMethod != null && calleeMethod == calleeMethod2) {
        calleeMethod2 = null;
        return returnValueOfConfirm;
    }
    noty({
        text: obj,
        buttons: [{
          text: 'Yes',
          onClick: function($noty) {
            $noty.close();
            noty({
              text: 'YES',
              type: 'success'
            });
          }
        }, {
          text: 'No',
          onClick: function($noty) {
            $noty.close();
            noty({
              text: 'NO',
              type: 'error'
            });
          }
        }]
    });
    throw new FatalError("!! Stop JavaScript Execution !!");
}

function runConfirmAgain() {
  calleeMethod2 = calleeMethod;
  // is a method
  if (calleeMethod != null) {
    var argsString = $(args).toArray().join("','");
    eval(calleeMethod2 + "('" + argsString + "')");
  } else {
    // is a if else confirm call
    alert('confirm error');
  }
}
```