# Ajax.Actionlink OnBegin confirmation will not prevent the ajax call from being called if the user click on "Cancel" button

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

i have the following ajax.actionlink:-

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Answer",
    new { id = answer.AnswersID },
      new AjaxOptions
      {
          OnBegin = "deleteconfirmation1",
          HttpMethod = "Post",
          UpdateTargetId = @answer.AnswersID.ToString(),
          OnSuccess = "deleteconfirmation",

      })
```

and the following deleteconfirmation1.js that should display a confirmation message before executing the ajax call:-

```
function deleteconfirmation1() {
jConfirm('Deletion Confirmation', 'Are you sure you want to delete this Answer');
}
```

**the problem that i am facing is that the onbegin confiramtion will not prevent the onsuccess script from being executed even if the user click on the cancel button? so how i can make the OnBegin to work as a confirmation stage, so the application will wait for the user selection either "Ok" or "cancel" before processding with the ajax call or not !!! ??**
BR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need return `false` from the `OnBegin` method to cancel the request.

Note that `Ajax.ActionLink` already supports confirmation with the [AjaxOptions.Confirm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.confirm.aspx) property.

You also need to include `~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` in your view/layout to use the `@Ajax.` helpers.

EDIT issue with [jConfirm](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/12/jquery-alert-dialogs/):

Your problem is that the signature of `jConfirm` is the following:

```
void jConfirm(message, [title, callback])
```

It's instead of returning true/false expects a callback function which is called when the user clicked on ok/cancel.

This causes the problem because you need to return `false` from the `OnBegin` but you don't have a return value from `jConfirm` just in the callback...

So you should wait for the callback.... see this SO question [Can you wait for javascript callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436608/can-you-wait-for-javascript-callback) 
(which is also about `jConfirm`) for more information.

The conclusion is that you cannot use `jConfirm` to cancel the request with the `OnBegin` method.

Comment: i am not using the AjaxOption.Confirm because i want to use customized java script confirm . second thing the deletion will be executed even if the JConfirm dialog is still displayed  before selecting Ok or Cancel that why i do not think that it is related to returning false or not .......

Comment: Try it with the built in `confirm` js function because it should work. It seams `jConfirm` does the confirmation async that's why the return value seems useless. Could you provide a link for `jConfirm`?

Comment: thanks for ur reply; here is the link http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/12/jquery-alert-dialogs/. regarding providing the built in confirm , i do not knwo from where i should call the buil in script in my ajax.actionliknk

Comment: I've updated my answer it seems `OnBegin` and the `jConfirm` plugin is not compatible...

Comment: thanks for you reply, so i will settle by using the ajaxoption.confirm instead , thnx